# I have a function that is supposed to be appending a value to an array but it isn't doing anything. Can someone help me?

Tags: python

```
def Product(number):

    Products = []
    for i in range(100,999):
        Products.append(number*i)


print(Product(300))
```

Comment: It does sth inside but you do not return anything

Comment: You build your list just fine. But you don't _return_ it, or anything else. So your function just returns the default `None` value. Just do a `return Products` at the end (indented at the same level as `for`, not `Products.append`) and it'll work.

Comment: As mentioned just `return` the list... note Python has some powerful list comprehension capabilities that would make this more concise, e.g. your function body could be replaced with `return [number*i for i in range(100, 999)]`

Answer (score 0):

Your function doesn't return anything.  This works:

```
def Product(number):

    Products = []
    for i in range(100,999):
        Products.append(number*i)
    return Products


print(Product(300))
```